# Physics of the Field Strength Coupling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

Is the field strength coupling of physical significance? Consider the Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
L=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4
\end{equation}
I have arbitrarily taken the co-efficient of the $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2$ to be $1$, and it seems this is often done. But if I were attempting to model a real physical statistical system, such as a real magnet, would I be modelling the system incorrectly if I took this co-efficient to be $1$? If not, then why is this co-efficient of no physical significance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What´s the importance of the normalization of the Kinetic term?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35155/what%c2%b4s-the-importance-of-the-normalization-of-the-kinetic-term)

Comment: In QFT the field strength is associated with the amplitude for the field operator to create a 1 particle state from the vacuum, see the discussion in Peskin&Schroeder part 7.1.

Comment: Your kinetic term can always be chosen to be $1$ by a rescaling of the field variable.